# Parsing table confusion

Tags: algorithms, parsers

I've been researching the different answers I've been given to this, would somebody just be able to give me a clear answer of the difference between

Shift, reduce and go-to. - In a parsing table.

Of course, reduce is in the same, but how do you know when to shift or go-to?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Which parsing algorithm? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: The terms are used in slightly different ways in some parsing algorithms. Study the explanation of the algorithm you have in ming closely, and ask again with specific questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

Goto is what you do after a reduce. It's very like a shift, except that it is handlng a non-terminal while shift handles a terminal.

A reduce action removes some items from the stack and uses them to create a non-terminal, which must then be pushed ("shifted") onto the stack. As with a shift action, pushing a non-terminal moves the state machine to a new state, which is why we call these table entries "goto" entries; they specify which state the state machine switches to.

A shift action is looked up in the transitions of the current state. A goto action is looked up in the transitions of the state "revealed" by popping the stack during the reduce action. In both cases, the effect is to move the dot in each of the state's items one position to the right, moving over a terminal (shift) or a non-terminal (goto).